# Why Am I Forced To Run This Code In Async?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

For some reason the code I have written is forcing me to run async code in a beforeEach block in Karma.

I am confused to how I can rewrite the below so that I run async code before my expectation without doing it in a beforeEach block.

```
  describe('SHOULD remove item whose ForecastTime is in the PAST', () => {

    loadStubs();

    stub[2].ActivityStages[0].ForecastStartTime = '2017-09-01T10:30:00.000'

    beforeEach(async(setup('2017-09-01T11:30:00.000', stub)));

    it('check', () => {

      expect(iRepository.parent.child[1].queue.length).toBe(1);

    });

  });
```

What I would like to do is...

```
  it('SHOULD remove item whose ForecastTime is in the PAST', () => {

    loadStubs();

    stub[2].ActivityStages[0].ForecastStartTime = '2017-09-01T10:30:00.000'

    async(setup('2017-09-01T11:30:00.000', stub))

    expect(iRepository.parent.child[1].queue.length).toBe(1);

  });
```

But my test fails. Does anyone know how I can do my expectation after the async code has definitely run?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Jasmine supports async for the moment.

You can read some more [here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1350).

An alternative could be for you to use [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) with [chai](http://chaijs.com/) and [chai as promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised).